# How is it possible to do spectral analysis of a light source?

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, instrument

I have a big book published many years ago by NASA which is page after page of numbers, the numbers being the irradiance of the sun at particular wavelengths.

I wonder how such a book could be composed. How would one determine the energy at one particular wavelength versus thousands and thousands and thousands of others?

I know that one could use filters to get a specific value. For example, one could construct a bandpass filter that would only allow light of a tightly limited range of wavelengths to pass through, but this would only allow the measurement of that one tiny range.

Comment: Think about prisms or diffraction gratings.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_spectrometer